# Why does struct need to conform to Hashable as well as Generic array when converting to a dictionary

Tags: swift, generics, hashable

The goal was to convert items in a generic list into a dictionary for the variable `uniqueKeys`, but I saw the error:

> Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

I knew something needed to conform to the `Hashable` protocol and eventually landed on the solution, but I don't completely understand why this solution works.

1. I understand why `T` needs to be `Hashable` since its' going into a dictionary key, but why also `CustomSet`?
2. If `CustomSet` uses `Hashable` why don't I need to write anything in its extension?

**initial code**

```
struct CustomSet<T : Comparable > {
    private var list: [T]
    init(_ list: [T]){
        let uniqueKeys = list.reduce(into: [:]){ dict, item in
            dict[item, default: 0] += 1
        }.keys
        self.list = Array(uniqueKeys)
    }
}

extension CustomSet : Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CustomSet, rhs: CustomSet) -> Bool {
        return lhs.list.count == rhs.list.count && lhs.list.sorted() == rhs.list.sorted()
    }
}
```

**I finally resolved it with:**

```
struct CustomSet<T : Comparable > : Hashable where T : Hashable {
    private var list: [T]
    init(_ list: [T]){
        let uniqueKeys = list.reduce(into: [:]){ dict, item in
            dict[item, default: 0] += 1
        }.keys
        self.list = Array(uniqueKeys)
    }
}

extension CustomSet : Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CustomSet, rhs: CustomSet) -> Bool {
        return lhs.list.count == rhs.list.count && lhs.list.sorted() == rhs.list.sorted()
    }
}
```

I also noticed that factoring into an extension: `extension CustomSet: Hashable where T : Hashable` doesn't seem to be the same as `struct CustomSet<T : Comparable > : Hashable where T : Hashable` in terms of adding the Hashable protocol because I still see that error

**What I tried**

If I add this to the generic type `T` I still saw the same error.

```
struct CustomSet<T : Comparable, Hashable >
```

If I add `Hashable` to `CustomSet` I see the error

> Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type
>   'UnsafeRawBufferPointer'

and

> Inheritance from non-protocol type 'Hashable'

```
extension CustomSet : Equatable, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: CustomSet, rhs: CustomSet) -> Bool {
        return lhs.list.count == rhs.list.count && lhs.list.sorted() == rhs.list.sorted()
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
       var hashValue: Int {
           var hasher = Hasher()
           self.hash(into: &hasher)
           return hasher.finalize()
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please start with the *problem,* not with the solution: Which code causes the initial error message “Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type” that you talk about?

Comment: `CustomSet` doesn't need to be `Hashable`, your code compiles just fine without the `Hashable` conformance. Btw what's the point of reducing a list into a `Dictionary`, whose keys are the elements of the list if then you're simply assigning the keys of said dictionary to `list`? You're not actually _unique-ing_ those keys.

Comment: @MartinR just added original code.

Comment: @DávidPásztor The dictionary will take an array like [1,1] and return a key of just 1 once - maybe I can rename it to `removeDuplicates`

Comment: @Turnipdabeets: Then I don't understand your question. As  Dávid says, CustomSet does not need to be Hashable. `struct CustomSet<T : Comparable & Hashable >` makes your initial code compile.

Comment: Oh! When I first tried  `struct CustomSet<T : Comparable, Hashable >` I was just missing the `&`  in `struct CustomSet<T : Comparable & Hashable >`

Comment: By the way, your equality will work the same if you remove `lhs.list.count == rhs.list.count`. If the struct is immutable, you can sort in the initializer.

Comment: Btw, there is a lot wrong with your custom Hashable implementation...

Comment: @MartinR It's incomplete, but happy to hear what you have to say!

Comment: @Turnipdabeets: For a starter, note that your `func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)` does nothing (apart from declaring an unused computed property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to make `CustomSet` conform to `Hashable`. Simply adding the `Hashable` restriction to the generic type parameter solves the error

> Cannot subscript a value of incorrect or ambiguous type

,which is expected, since a `Dictionary`'s keys need to conform to `Hashable`.

Btw the syntax for declaring conformance to several protocols is `&`, not `,`, so there's no need for the where clause.

```
struct CustomSet<T : Comparable & Hashable> {
    private var list: [T]
    init(_ list: [T]){
        let uniqueKeys = list.reduce(into: [:]){ dict, item in
            dict[item, default: 0] += 1
            }.keys
        self.list = Array(uniqueKeys)
    }
}

extension CustomSet : Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: CustomSet, rhs: CustomSet) -> Bool {
        return lhs.list.count == rhs.list.count && lhs.list.sorted() == rhs.list.sorted()
    }
}
```

Moreover, you can simply do `self.list = Array(Set(list))` in the initializer to store only the unique elements from the input in your `list`, there's no need for messing around with a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thanks Dávid, I'm avoiding using Set because I'm writing my own CustomSet :)

Comment: @Turnipdabeets a `Set` is just simplified `Dictionary`. If you don't want to use a `Set`, then using `Dictionary` is cheating :)